# Python while loop not breaking when condition met

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax

I realize I'm probably making some really basic syntax error, but I'm having trouble fixing or googling this.

I want a process to stop when a certain limit is reached. Seems like a perfect use case for a while loop. However...

```
test_list = []

integers = list(range(40))

while len(test_list) < 20:
    for i in integers:
        test_list.append(i)
```

this will run through the entire `integers` list rather than stopping halfway through.

`len(test_list) < 20` now returns `false`. shouldn't the loop be breaking when the condition is reached?

Comment: You have a nested for loop which will fill the test_list and the while loop will exit on the second iteration. If you don't understand put a print statement below while and one below test_list.append()

Comment: the ``while`` is enclosing the ``for``, thus the ``for`` will run for a full cycle before the ``while`` will check the condition (again). You should get rid of at least one of these loops. Lookup ``slicing`` to see how this can be done w/o loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has occurred as the entire `for`-loop is executed in the 1st iteration of `while`-loop. This populates the list and then checks for the condition in the 2nd iteration of your `while` loop.

This can be solved as below:

```
test_list = []

integers = list(range(40))

for i in integers:
    test_list.append(i)
    if len(test_list) >= 20:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, the `while` condition is not evaluated all the time, but only when the control flow reaches that point, i.e. before and after the `for` loop, but not in between. In cases like this (combined `while` and `for`) you could use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) instead:

```
from itertools import takewhile
for i in takewhile(lambda _: len(test_list) < 20, integers):
    test_list.append(i)
```

This will execute the loop as long as (a) there are more elements in the iterable, and (b) the condition holds. Thus, `test_list` ends up as `[0, 1, ..., 19]`

But of course, in this *very* particular case, you could also just do `test_list = integers[:20]`.